# Notation for confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, notation

Since P(lower bound estimate < true parameter < upper bound estimate) = 0.95 means that the series of random bounds contain the true parameter 95 percent of the times, then why not replace the brackets with braces as P{lower bound estimate < true parameter < upper bound estimate} = 0.95 to make it explicit that we are talking about a series of bounds and that the bound we estimate is just one of them. Otherwise one is easily inclined to read the first expression as that the true parameter falls within the estimated bound with 95 percent probability, which is wrong. I am not sure if the use of a brace is good but I am also not satisfied with the first expression. Could the braces indeed address the confusion the first expression leads to?

Comment: Could you explain what distinction you think the use of braces might be making compared to using parentheses?  Otherwise, this appears to be a matter of opinion and typography rather than a substantive statistical question.

Comment: That we have a series of intervals rather than one interval to appreciate the repeated sampling notion that underlies the confidence interval. I am not a mathematician and hence I am not claiming whether the use of a brace is (strictly) suitable. But I am not satisfied with the parenthesis.

Comment: But how would braces make that distinction?  This sounds like a discussion you might enjoy having on chat rather than a real question about statistics.

Comment: Give the first expression to a student and ask him to read it. He will read it as I explained in the OP. I do not like that. I am looking for a better notation that leads one to read the confidence interval correctly. Does not a brace indicate that we are talking about a series? Do not we sometimes write {x_i} to denote that x_i is a random variable? The bounds of the CI are random.

Comment: I think you assume far too much of notation.  Braces can mean literally anything: a set, a series, a sequence, a Stirling number, *etc.*  Indeed, your use of braces around $x_i$ to designate a random variable is quite unusual.  Changing notation is not going to teach people what confidence intervals are.  What, then, is your question?  In rereading your post I see a proposal but no statistical question.

Comment: We have a series, or a set, of intervals. So why a brace is not suitable here? I am simply asking what notation we could use to avoid the ambiguity in the first expression in the OP. What is not clear about my question?